# Laptop not detecting my home wifi

Tags: wireless

I m using Ubuntu 14.04. My laptop is not detecting my home wifi network. But my mobile detects my home wifi and connects well. And my laptop detects and connects to other wifi networks except my home network.

Comment: Other solutions here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/889201/my-home-wifi-ssid-is-not-visible-in-ubuntu (broadcom wifi card not detecting channel 13...)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling the driver? Because if it had to be manually installed try and see if you can reinstall. Ubuntu 16.04 was just released a few hours ago. so you can try and see if it will connect to wifi in the live CD/USB

Comment: I am new to Ubuntu. How to reinstall the driver? And sorry my USB port is not working

Comment: to be honest I dont know ubuntu that much either. you could wait for someone to help you out soon. you could try videos or other fourms but honestly I do not know :(

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Just changed the name of my WiFi network. 
Thanks