# My Home Wifi SSID is not visible in Ubuntu

Tags: wireless

I have a strange problem. I can see other Wifi SSID in my Ubuntu system. But my home Wifi name is not listed. And hence not connected.

Strangely this particular Wifi is visible to my other devices. In windows, android, mac etc.

I think it has to do this particular wifi's channel. But I can't confirm. I can't access my home wifi router page, not in any devices. If I could I could tweak the channel, and give it a try.

How to get this particular wifi name listed under available wifi connections in Ubuntu/ I am using ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to it as it was a hidden ssid?

Comment: Are any other devices connected to it? Phones, tablets, etc.? What do they say the channel or frequency is? Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `sudo iw reg get`.

Comment: @chili555 that command gives this - country 00: DFS-UNSET

Comment: @Cyber_Star not hidden, I already tried.

Comment: Is it channel 13 ? Do you have a broadcom wifi card ? If not wih one with which driver ?

Comment: Use wifi analyzer to know which channel it is on: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer&hl=fr

Comment: @solsTiCe yup broadcom. Will install and check the wifi channel tomorrow. Night here. No leave for me for this Saturday.

Comment: @solsTiCe yes it's channel 13.

Comment: This is a known problem with broadcom wl driver and channel 13. Change the channel or give up.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to tell the wifi stack in which part of the world you are in. This is to comply with regulation of your country regarding the emission of electromagnetic wave.

If this is not already done, install the `crda` package with `sudo apt install crda`. You configure it by changing `/etc/default/crda` file by setting *REGDOMAIN* to your country 2 letter iso 3166-1 alpha 2 code. In our example, I guess it is **IN**

As most of the country outside the US, this enable us to use the channel 12 and 13.

After a reboot, you should be able to see channel 12 and 13 SSID/AP.

You could check that the coutry has been set in the wifi stack by checking the country code with

```
iw reg get
```

If you still don't see your SSID, then you might be using broadcom driver and hitting a bug.